# getting error when i compile c program through putty

Tags: c, linux

```
/tmp/ccfg3L9u.o: In function `main':
Allgo-API-Test.c:(.text+0x968): undefined reference to `mport_get_sub_metadata_entries'
Allgo-API-Test.c:(.text+0xb24): undefined reference to `mport_set_play_scope'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'bin/MediaPort.elf' failed
make: *** [bin/MediaPort.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: Fix your makefile. Looks like it's missing a library or object file. Can't really give a better answer without more info...

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to link additional library while compiling file **`Allgo-API-Test.c`**

Before compiling this file you should have library which contain definition of `mport_get_sub_metadata_entries` and `mport_set_play_scope`. Once you get that library you can use below command to compile.

```
g++ Allgo-API-Test.c -l(your library) [-L(path to your library)]
```

Comment: ya its correct. i missed library files. thank you for your comment